# How to implement SSO in Node.JS Azure AD B2C

Tags: node.js, azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, passport-azure-ad

I have 4 Node.JS Application frontend angular with different domains, I have implemented Azure AD B2C

I need to implement SSO or Single Sign On in my applications

How can I set it up, what is the recommended way.

I checked https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad

but there is no documentation on setting up SSO for Node.JS applications or sample codes.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Azure AD B2C->User flows(policies)->find your sign in policy->properties->you will find the single sign-on configuration.

[image]

The default setting is **tenant** which allows multiple applications and user flows in your B2C tenant to share the same user session. For example, once a user signs into an application, the user can also seamlessly sign into another one.

Reference:

[Configure session behavior in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for providing details, but there is no implementation documentation of SSO for Node.JS